# d20 natural 1 specific question

Tags: probability, dice

I think this is quite a difficult problem, but here goes:

> If you roll $54$ $20$-sided dice, what is the probability of rolling a $1$ 10 times?

Comment: Is this "rolling a $1$ *exactly* ten times" or "rolling a $1$ *at least* ten times"?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) to solve this question. The probability $p$ of hitting $1$ equals $\frac{1}{20},$ so the probability of rolling this value $10$ times in $54$ rolls equals:

$${54 \choose 10} \bigg(\frac{1}{20}\bigg)^{10} \bigg(\frac{19}{20}\bigg)^{44} \approx 0.000245$$